# In Excel 2010 - Trying to get the cell address from where a formula got its answer

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a complex spreadsheet with a named range (Vault) that covers chunks of data from many parts of the sheet:

[image: Score Page]

"Vault" represents a defined name and refers to the following areas on page 1 (you can see the column heading in the different areas):

```
'Score Page'!$C$8:$C$31
'Score Page'!$K$8:$K$20
'Score Page'!$C$36:$C$47
'Score Page'!$K$25:$K$30
'Score Page'!$K$35:$K$41
'Score Page'!$C$52:$C$57
'Score Page'!$K$47:$K$57
```

(In the image above, the ranges below row 35 are out of view)

On this sheet, I Have the athlete name, school and the scores received for the 4 events for all participating.  I use the LARGE function to pull the top score for the Vault event:

```
=Large(vault,1)
```

This gets placed on a result page (separate Sheet from Athlete info):

[image: Results]

I need a formula that will tell me the cell address for where the LARGE function pulled the number.  There could be ties (and usually are ties) so MAX is out.  I have no experience with VBA so I really need to do this using formulas.

I can get the top score with the "Large" function but can't seem to figure out the formula to pull the name and school to go with that score on the result page.  Right now I do this by physically looking at the raw data page to find the score I get on the result page and typing in the information.

I do have a column with a formula also that will put the place of that score (1st, 2nd 3rd etc)  and account for ties so I could have 1st, 2nd, 2nd, third, etc.

On the results page, the columns are Place (under the event label), School, Athlete Name, and Score.  So far I can get Place and Score to happen.

My thought is if I can get the cell address for where the value of the formula LARGE(vault,1) is pulling its answer I can use that cell address to get the other addresses to pull the school and kids name.  Under typical circumstances, I could lookup the result in the data to find its location using a function like VLOOKUP or MATCH.  However, the fact that the named range covers many separate areas on the sheet complicates that kind of approach.

To recap, the problem is to find the cell that the LARGE function found its result in.

Comment: Use INDEX plus MATCH.  MATCH will find the score in the column from which it was chosen.  Index will then use that position to select the value from another column for the same row.  Some help: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html.  If the scores were in the first column, you could use VLOOKUP.  INDEX+MATCH doesn't have that restriction.  If you have trouble figuring it out, post a mockup of your data in your answer and someone can base an answer on that.  Another link to Microsoft help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214142

Comment: Vlookup won't work as there are multiple columns that the info comes from.  I will investigate the Index plus match options.

Comment: If you can't figure it out, add a mockup of your data to your question.  MATCH will have the same issue if the lookup can reference different columns.  (VLOOKUP has the additional problem that the lookup must be done in the left-most column).

Comment: the formula I am currently using on the results page is "Large(vault,1)"  where "Vault" represents several areas on the raw data page for the vault scores not all in the same column.  What I want to do is have a formula that basically goes along the line of - I want the cell address where the value of Large(vault,1) was found.  I can't seem  to figure out how to get the mock up of my data to show here.

Comment: It takes less than a minute to create a Dropbox account. You may already have a OneDrive account. Or a Google account. All these can be used to share files. Without a data sample I cannot picture how ' "Vault" represents several areas on the raw data page for the vault scores not all in the same column.' If you want to reverse the formula that uses "Vault" then we need to know what "Vault" consists of. Better than a screenshot would be a sample file. Again, Dropbox, OneDrive, Google.

Comment: "Vault" is an excel "name" which represents a group of cells I defined on the raw data page.

Comment: ok hope I've done this right  here is the drop box link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmdw1oeftxz217r/team%20excel%20sheet.docx   "Vault" represents a defined name and refers to the following areas on page 1   ='Score Page'!$C$8:$C$31,'Score Page'!$K$8:$K$20,'Score Page'!$C$36:$C$47,'Score Page'!$K$25:$K$30,'Score Page'!$K$35:$K$41,'Score Page'!$C$52:$C$57,'Score Page'!$K$47:$K$57

Comment: Thanks to who ever edited and added the sample.  I only showed the first schools with part of the other schools as it is all the same below for the other 5 schools.  On the result page I'm trying to get the school name and the name of the athlete to fill in so I don't have to do it manually.  the 4 highlighted cells are the scores that are added up to get the team score.  The red numbers means that out of all the schools this is one of the top 3 scores for that event.  Only the top 3 (including ties) ends up on the result pages for each event (there are a total of 4 events not just Vault)

Comment: I would love help with the MATCH function as I have tried to use that with Index and If but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: There is also a Large formula for bars, beam, floor and all around (AA) scores that will give me the places for 1st through 7th.  So instead of the number 1 in the Large formula there would be a #2 and so on.

Comment: Are the school names actually "1", "2", etc. or are those just placeholders?  Is all of the structural information (names, event participation, etc.), known in advanced and doesn't change or might you modify the tables, move blocks to create extra space, etc.?  Do you just leave some blank lines in each table to cover that potential need?  Ties can happen within a school as well as between schools?

Comment: I've made several attempts at an answer but each time, I find another complication.  Using this kind of structure as a starting point makes the problem a bear.  The easiest way to get to the end result would be a different starting point.  Have the data in a form that can be easily queried and create the score page display from that, so it is just presenting formatted data from somewhere else.  The actual data would be a single table containing everything.

Comment: OK SO IF I CHANGE THE FORMAT SO ALL THE NAMES ARE IN COLUMN A, ALL THE SCHOOL NAMES ARE IN COLUMN B AND ALL THE SCORES ARE IN COLUMN C WITH NO SPACES BETWEEN THE TEAMS WHAT WOULD YOU WRITE FOR THE INDEX/MATCH FORMULA TO GET WHAT I WANT ON THE RESULTS PAGE?

Answer (score 1):

=CELL("address",Large(vault,1))

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  Thanks.